# Calling User Location from AppDelegate through Different View

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am trying to use my appDelegate to get a user's location from another view. I could save it in NSUserDefaults, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

My AppDelegate contains this:

```
- (NSString *)deviceLocation
{
NSString *userCoordinates = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", 
locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, 
locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

return userCoordinates;

}
```

Then I want to call the user's location from another page with this:

```
//Get the User's Location
NSString *location =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate deviceLocation];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This don't work because the deviceLocation method in the AppDelegate don't return anything.

If you want to alert your current location the deviceLocation should return something (i.e a NSString with the current location).

Then display it with something like this

```
NSString *location =[(PDCAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate deviceLocation];

//Alert
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Location" 
message:location delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, 
nil];
[alert show];
```

Comment: I am getting two errors when I add "return latString" at the end of the code. 1)void method device location should not return a value. and 2) implicit conversion of an objective c pointer to void is disalowed with ARC. Any ideas?

Comment: the method signature shouldn't contain void if you're returning an object.
- (NSString *)deviceLocation

Comment: Another odd thing; is the locationManager an instance variable? Why are you initiating it after the first usage?

Comment: Im working off of some sample code. Is that a bad way to do it?

Comment: The question in this case is WHY are you doing it? :) If it isn't already initiated it will fail. If it's already initiated, why do it again?

Comment: I have updated question with my current code. This is what I am working off of now, but I am getting an error when I try to call the NSString *location the way you had recommended. the error says no visible @interface for PDCAppDelegate declares in the selector device location. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't return 3 objects. If you want to return 3 strings you should return an array containing strings.

Comment: I am just trying to put it somewhere that it can be accessed at any time. I thought the appDelegate would be the right place. Looks like Im way off on this...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21198/discussion-between-johan-and-brandon)